# RestTemplateBuilder- 403 forbidden error

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, http-status-code-403, resttemplate

Below is how I am coding the SSL handshake using springboot framework. I get a 403 forbidden error. I am able to access the web service from browser by uploading the client cert but not via application on my server. How to troubleshoot this issue?  Below is ClientSSLConfiguration class.

```
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) throws   Exception {
SSLContext sslContext;
sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
            .create()
            .loadKeyMaterial(keystore,    storePass().toCharArray())
            .loadTrustMaterial(truststore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())               
         .build();

    HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
           .build();        

    return builder
            .requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))                
            .build();
}
```

//Client Method call

```
restTemplate = clientSSLConfiguration
                .restTemplate(new RestTemplateBuilder());
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                REST_API_ENDPOINT, String.class);
```